# How to delete a specific row in a text file using fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

Good Day! My problem is I should delete a whole specific row in my text file. But instead, I am just replacing it with white space. Actually, I have no idea how to delete the row. Here is my code:

```
fstream fs("FoodList.txt");
//charPos here is the position in file where I should begin deleting.
fs.seekp(charPos);
//I loop 100 times because I am sure that each row is 100 characters.
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    //What I really want to do is to delete the whole row
    fs << " ";
}
```

My text file would look like this:
Before:

```
apple
banana
carrot
cherry
```

After(if I choose `charPos = 3`):

```
apple
banana
cherry
```

By the way, I have already made the Update part where I can EDIT specific rows. Any help will be appreciated! :)

Comment: How are you editing the file? ARe the lines all the same length?

Comment: @doctorlove the in-code comment `"I am sure that each row is 100 characters."` seems to indicate that is the case.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to read in the file, write out to a temporary file, excluding the selected line and to move the temporary file to the original one.

Comment: This and if you are working linebased think about using `getline`

Comment: pass every line in a vector then write it to the temp file?

Comment: @RalphDeGuzman: that is a possibility, but not necessary.  Of course if you store all lines in a vector, then you can close the input file and overwrite it without using a temporary file.  Using a temporary file is a little bit safer when something happens during processing.

Comment: @stefaanv Can you please show me the piece of code on how to do exclude a specific line? I really have no idea how to do it and I can't see any good answer while searching the net.

Comment: @RalphDeGuzman Like this: `if(!exclude(line)) write(line);` Where `exclude(line)` is a conditional expression resulting in whether you want to exclude the line and `write` pushes the line to a vector or writes the line in a temporary file depending on the chosen approach.

Comment: It should be similar to finding the line that you want to overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a bad way to do this, but i have found a simple way to do this.

```
    while(!fs.eof())
    {
        fs << '\0';
    }
```

This code will erase the whole text after your position in the File.

by the way: fs.eof() tells you if you are at the end of the stream

for setting your position you can use this:

```
fs.seekp(streampos pos);
```

If you just want to delete the text between yout position an the next spaces, Tabstop or enter you just use the the single line shown in the loop, but I think you know that (:

I hope this will help you